# Find all records where between 2 dates have a certain value for each record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with vacation houses which have some availability (column `value`, value `1` means available ).
How can I find all houses (column `unit_id`) that are are available between 2 dates.

**table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `houseavailability` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `houseavailability_unit_id_IDX` (`unit_id`,`date`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `houseavailability_unit_id_IDX_solo` (`unit_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16648943 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**test data**

```sql
INSERT INTO houseavailability
(id, `date`, value, unit_id)
VALUES(15814115, '2022-07-23', '1', '1004004');
INSERT INTO houseavailability
(id, `date`, value, unit_id)
VALUES(15814116, '2022-07-24', '1', '1004004');
INSERT INTO houseavailability
(id, `date`, value, unit_id)
VALUES(15814117, '2022-07-25', '1', '1004004');
INSERT INTO houseavailability
(id, `date`, value, unit_id)
VALUES(15814118, '2022-07-26', '1', '1004004');
INSERT INTO houseavailability
(id, `date`, value, unit_id)
VALUES(15814119, '2022-07-27', '1', '1004004');
INSERT INTO houseavailability
(id, `date`, value, unit_id)
VALUES(15814120, '2022-07-28', '1', '1004004');
INSERT INTO houseavailability
(id, `date`, value, unit_id)
VALUES(15814121, '2022-07-29', '1', '1004004');
INSERT INTO houseavailability
(id, `date`, value, unit_id)
VALUES(15814122, '2022-07-30', '0', '1004004');
```

**attempt**

```sql
SELECT houseavailability.*
FROM houseavailability
WHERE houseavailability.date BETWEEN '2022-07-23' AND '2022-07-30'
AND houseavailability.unit_id = 1004004;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/094547/2

Comment: What's your expect result and what's your MySQL version?

Comment: @D-Shih a list of unit_id's where between 2 dates every record in between has the value 1.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Close, however this does not guarantee that all records have the value 1, it just gives back all the rows for which this is true/ However for 1 it's not.

Comment: ok i have removed mine comment i misunderstood what you where looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the condition aggregate function in `HAVING` to compare whether all the rows for which this is `true` between your date condition.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT unit_id
FROM houseavailability
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-07-23' AND '2022-07-30'
GROUP BY unit_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT date) = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN value = '1' THEN date END)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/094547/42/0)**:

`DISTINCT` which is in aggregate function will count only once, if there are duplicate days have 1 value in your tables, but if you want to count multiple when you met that situation you can remove `DISTINCT` from the aggregate function.

**EDIT**

Due to there being a `UNIQUE` constraint from your `unit_id` and `date` columns, you don't need to use `DISTINCT` on your aggregate function.

```
SELECT unit_id
FROM houseavailability
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-07-23' AND '2022-07-30'
GROUP BY unit_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN value = '1' THEN date END)
```

Comment: No `DISTINCT date` requierd when grouping by `unit_id` because of `UNIQUE KEY houseavailability_unit_id_IDX (unit_id,date) ` and `WHERE` condition excludes NULL dates.

Comment: @Serg You are right, I didn't see the unique constraint before your mention, thanks for your reminder.

Comment: I prefer this answer as this also works without the value being an integer that can be summed.

Answer (score 3):

For example, find a  `unit_id` which is available during the whole specified period.

```
SELECT unit_id
FROM houseavailability
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-07-23' AND '2022-07-30'
GROUP BY unit_id
HAVING sum(value) = datediff('2022-07-30','2022-07-23') + 1;
```

Comment: You were first and obviously have a great answer, but as I commented on the other answer: I like that one more as it is more of a general solution for this problem, that also works with non-integers. Upvote well deserved for you also of course.

Comment: @onlineThomas, it's OK.